# Generating new Tz1 account from Taquito

Tags: taquito

In ConseilJs, there is a KeyStoreUtils which helps generate mnemonic and restore it to an account. Are there any ways in taquito library to perform similar action? Or do we need to install and import tezbridge crypto lib library to perform the action

Answer (score 0):

No, it seems Taquito doesn't have this functionality, As an alternative you also have sotez: https://github.com/AndrewKishino/sotez